# Is it possible to add translation variables automatically in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, automation, translation

I've got a few blades and I have included there many appeals like this:

```
    <div>{{ __('auth.Example') }}</div>
    <a href='#'>{{ __('xyz.Another One Example') }}</a>
    <span>{{ __('xyz.Example Number Three') }}</span>
    ...
```

I added `xyz.php` and `auth.php` files to `lang/en` and `lang/pl` directories. Now I'm wondering, **is it possible to use some command or method, which will add to these files proper variables to refill?**
I don't except ready translation, but something like that would be appreciated:

**xyz.php**

```
return [
...
'Another One Example' => 'Another One Example',
'Example Number Three' => 'Example Number Three',
...
];
```

**auth.php**

```
return [
...
'Example' => 'Example'
...
];
```

After that I could quickly change translation values for proper languages, but firstly I need to have right variables in proper files. For now I'm copying every single variable to proper file manually, but it feels like an eternity... Have you any ideas, how could I do it easier?

Comment: Sure, you can get a package like this https://github.com/ben182/laravel-auto-translate to do that step for you.

Answer (score 1):

I previously wrote a script like this. I used the function below which scans all files and uses regex to detect translation keys.

```
function findTranslationKeys($grep, $path, $regex)
{
    $keys = [];

    $filenames = glob(base_path() . $path . '/**/**');

    foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
        if (preg_match_all($regex, file_get_contents($filename), $matches)) {
            foreach ($matches[1] as $index => $match) {   
                $keys[$match] = $match;
            }
        }
    }

    return $keys;
}

 $keys = $this->findTranslationKeys( '/resources/views', '/__\(\'([^\']*)\'[^\)]*/s');
```

You can load in the existing translations with

```
 $filePath = base_path() . '/resources/lang/en/' . $file . '.php';

 if (file_exists($filePath)) {
     $existing = require $filePath;
 } else {
     $existing = [];
 }
```

Add any missing translations to the files, and then write the files back with

```
$fh = fopen($filePath, 'w');
fwrite($fh, "<?php\n");
fwrite($fh, 'return ' . var_export($existing, true) . ';');
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Wow Liam, I love your answer, it's brilliant! That's exactly, what I was looking for. Unfortunately, I'm a begginer in Laravel, so I'm not sure, how to overcome some issues. I found, that sometimes I used `"` instead of `'` in my translation keys, so I changed regex for `'/__\((\'|\")([^\'\"]*)(\'|\")[^\)]*/s'` and I believe that works. But I realized that my `$filenames` variable is always empty. I'm using Win7, may it be a problem with `grep`? Accoring to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/300815/grep-equivalent-for-windows-7) I changed `grep` for `findstr`, but it didn't help

Comment: Yea thats a good point, grep may not be available on Windows by default. I think you could try running it inside Git Bash or Windows Subsystem for Linux, but alternatively maybe you could tweak the code to use `glob(base_path() . '/resources/views/**/**') instead, which would return all files and scan them all.

Comment: Tested and the above seems to work nicely, so updated my answer

Comment: Great, it doesn't match files with are put directly in views directory and in directories with are deeper than two directories like `views/auth/passwords/email.blade.php`, but I can handle it. Now I'm struggling with overcome a new problem: `ErrorException file_get_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\resources\views\auth): failed to open stream: Permission denied (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\resources\views\home.blade.php)`